# Finding the expectation value given an operator in the form of a matrix and wave vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I was wondering how one would find the expectation value $\langle \hat{S} \rangle$ where $\hat{S}$ is just any operator in the form a matrix, such as the identity matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and using a wave-vector such as $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}$.

I know that it is $\langle \hat{S} \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{S} | \psi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x |\psi (x)|^2 dx$, however the problem is that I have a wave vector, not a wave-function so I do not have to evaluate this operation. Could anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that it is $\langle \hat{S} \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{S} | \psi \rangle$ but in this case since your vector $|\psi \rangle$ only has finitely many components in (compare to a function $\psi(x)$ which effectively has one component per real number $x$) you don't use an integral to calculate that inner product.

How can I tell? Well, we know

$$|\psi \rangle =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}$$

And $\langle \psi | = (|\psi \rangle )^\dagger$, where the "dagger" $\dagger$ symbol is just the conjugate transpose for finite-component vectors. So

$$\langle \psi | = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}$$

Finally, plug in S and just do the matrix multiplications until you get a single number:

$$\langle \psi | S |\psi \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} S_{11} & S_{12} \\ S_{21} & S_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I would like to know why in the process of getting the conjugate transpose you get the same component, i.e. instead of $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 3}$ you get $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 3}$ ? Many thanks.

Comment: @user996159 Thanks for pointing that out, it was an error! Now it is fixed.